# Save form data in modal class that contains an array [Angular]

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, angular, typescript

How can I save form data that contains an array.so I faced an issue which is the adresses is null whereas other data like city region aren't null. someone here have an idea ?!

**Iuser.interface**

```
 export interface UserData {
    id: string;
    email: string;
    adresses: string[];

  }
```

**Component.ts**

```
onSubmit() {

    const {adresse1, ...rest} = this.form;

    const userData: UserData = {...rest, adresses: [adresse1]};

    this.userservice.updateProfile(userData, this.currentUser.id).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.isSuccessful = true;
      },
      err => {
        this.errorMessage = err.error.message;
      }
    );
  }
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=""
            name="adresse"
            [(ngModel)]="form.adresse"
            required
            #adresse="ngModel">

  </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
<div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label>Region</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"
      name="region"
      [(ngModel)]="form.region"
      required
      #region="ngModel">
    </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
```

[image]

Comment: I do not see any problem in the above code,  Are you getting any error ? What is your desired output ?

Comment: In request payload  adresses: [null]
0: null but other variable city country region contain data

Comment: pls post form code. Also, I believe it should be this.form.value

Comment: Yes please show what `console.log(this.form)` yields

Comment: Typo in `form.adresse` ?

Comment: you can check it I update my question

Comment: @ShijilNarayan console.log(data); show all the form data except adresses is null & for email it saved correctly

Comment: Please check my ans

Comment: pls post .ts where you initialize this.form. It seems like you are mixing template driven and reactive forms

Comment: @ihorbond  form: any = {}; const {adresse1, ...rest} = this.form;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading `adresse1` from `this.form` inside `onSubmit()` method which is not a part of your form object,your address is actually stored in`adresse` property.Please update your code within submit block as

```
const {adresse, ...rest} = this.form;
const userData: UserData = {...rest, adresses: [adresse]};
```

Comment: you mean edit html form to this [(ngModel)]="form.adresse1"N??

Comment: Yes , you need to change it to form. adresse1 and it would work

Comment: Please try updating your html as I included in the ans

Comment: Still not working other variable are changed except adresse & city..

Comment: Can you show what all you get when you `console.log(this.form)` within submit method, need to see the entire object

Comment: I add a pic as an answer

Comment: Please add that to the question :)

Comment: Your html was okay,change it back to how it was initially,  pls check my updated ans now and try that

Comment: I faced The same problem now just inside adresses there are adresse What I want is to insert city region... into adresses: string[];

Comment: Please show what your  final adresses array should look like

Comment: in the backend here is what looks like & that's working on postman {
  "adresse": {
            
            "adresse": "Quartier salam",
            "ville": "Tiznit",
            "code_postal": 400044,
            "region": "Souss",
            "pays": "Maroc"
        },
        "nom": "ind",
        "prenom": "klt"
}

Comment: There is no array in this object you sending in postman, why are you passing adresses as an array from code ?

Comment: Yeah I know in backend user model contains @DBRef Adresse adresse in frontend I don't know how can I send it if you know how share it with me I'l be glad